# Numpy Array index problems

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having a small issue understanding indexing in Numpy arrays. I think a simplified example is best to get an idea of what I am trying to do.
So first I create an array of zeros of the size I want to fill:

```
x = range(0,10,2)
y = range(0,10,2)
a = zeros(len(x),len(y))
```

so that will give me an array of zeros that will be 5X5. Now, I want to fill the array with a rather complicated function that I can't get to work with grids. My problem is that I'd like to iterate as:

```
for i in xrange(0,10,2):
    for j in xrange(0,10,2):
          .........
    "do function and fill the array corresponding to (i,j)"
```

however, right now what I would like to be a[2,10] is a function of 2 and 10 but instead the index for a function of 2 and 10 would be a[1,4] or whatever.

Again, maybe this is elementary, I've gone over the docs and find myself at a loss.

EDIT:
In the end I vectorized as much as possible and wrote the simulation loops that I could not in Cython. Further I used Joblib to Parallelize the operation. I stored the results in a list because an array was not filling right when running in Parallel. I then used Itertools to split the list into individual results and Pandas to organize the results. 
Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tips for your to get the things done keeping a good performance:

```
- avoid Python `for` loops
- create a function that can deal with vectorized inputs
```

Example:

```
def f(xs, ys)
    return x**2 + y**2 + x*y
```

where you can pass `xs` and `ys` as arrays and the operation will be done element-wise:

```
xs = np.random.random((100,200))
ys = np.random.random((100,200))

f(xs,ys)
```

You should read more about [`numpy` broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to get a better understanding about how the arrays's operations work. This will help you to design a function that can handle properly the arrays.

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at broadcasting and I am trying to make the function vectorized, I agree that it would improve performance markedly. But part of the function is iterative in nature and that makes it hard for me to vectorize.

Comment: It would be nice then if you could give more details about your function, maybe you can get a better support..., also, take a look at Cython, which can significantly improve required for loops...

Answer (score 0):

First, you lack some parenthesis with zeros, the first argument should be a tuple :

```
a = zeros((len(x),len(y)))
```

Then, the corresponding indices for your table are i/2 and j/2 :

```
for i in xrange(0,10,2):
    for j in xrange(0,10,2):
        # do function and fill the array corresponding to (i,j)
        a[i/2, j/2] = 1
```

But I second Saullo Castro, you should try to vectorize your computations.